# How can auto sync cells in two excel files?

Tags: vba, excel

How Can sync Excel Cell's of different Document?. I would like to have two excel cell's on different Workbook to have the same information.

For Example: Let say i have  `Excel1.xls - Sheet1: Cell A1 = 400571` i would like:   `Excel2 - Sheet1:A1` to have the same information.

And if the content of `Excel1/Sheet1/ A1` is changed i would like to change the value on `Excel2.csv/Sheet1/A1`.

Thank you!

Comment: How would you know which A1 is the "correct" value?  You'd have to do this real-time using a `WorkSheet_Change` event handler in each workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. Well the file names are different, and can you give me example on how to use `WorkSheet_Change` event. Thanks

Comment: Sorry - I mis-read your question.  Is the second file really a CSV and not xls ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks! that wasn't your mistake i was wrong when typing it. i changed it after your comment. Yes one of them is xls and the other one .csv

Comment: CSV files don't have Sheets (or ranges), so it's not going to be straightforward to sync up a CSV with an Excel file.  You can either re-write the whole CSV from Excel1 or somehow open up the CSV (in Excel) and then update it.  Either way, it's not straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to search Google:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-link-to-another-cell-workbook-or-program-HP005199514.aspx

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1604/excel_how_to_reference_cells_in_other_worksheets/

Comment: These links do not address the OP's question: formulas will not work for this application - you will get a "circular reference" error.

Comment: Sheet 1 is the source of data.  The OP wants that source data replicated in multiple workbooks.  The only cells with formulas are the ones linking back to the source.  Therefore, not a circular reference...  Unless I am completely missing something in the OP's question.

Comment: @bp - My bad: it was me who did not read the question correctly.  Although if the second file is really a CSV that might be a problem.  If you can edit your answer a little bit I can remove my hasty -1 (seems like it's locked-in unless you edit)

Comment: Edited.  And if it's a .csv I'm not sure this is even possible.  Unless the code is held inside a workbook that opens the .csv

Comment: Thanks!! works great! for a single cell but what if i what to copy whole column instead of a single cell?

Comment: @Kuku, a column is simply a collection of cells.  Copy the cell with the formula and paste it into the cells you want to contain the formula.  I would suggest using autofill.  Also, ensure your formula has the locked references ($) in the appropriate places.